# Форма обратной связи лишь цифры на клавиатуре

Tags: javascript

Интересует такой вопрос есть сайт на  `Yii2`, как сделать так чтобы при клике в форме обратной связи на номер телефона, на клавиатуре телефона были доступны [лишь цифры](http://prntscr.com/o9fcby)?

Comment: Попробуйте `<input type="number">`

Comment: То, что у вас на изображении может быть и маской.

Comment: Так же есть в html5 и `type="tel"`, но там у браузеров поддержка немного меньше.

Comment: Так же можно поставить `type="number"` а скриптом в `try catch` перебивать на tel. Если tel поддерживается - будет tel, если нет - будет number.

Comment: Как можно определить поддерживается ли number или tel ?
даже если предположить что браузер сам определяет
как это определить потом мне?

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-email-tel-url